# Passing an array as parameters in a search filter with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Hi I got a search filter page and I have a field that's a multiple select so it's value is an array. Is it possible to pass that input's value (w/c is an array) as a parameter or should I use sessions?

Thanks!

Comment: This question needs way more details, possibly peppered with some actual code.

Comment: Your choices are really just pass as parameter in the URL or pass as POST payload.  Sessions are only helpful once the data is already received by the server, from the client.  I'm afraid you'll need to provide significantly more details before anyone can assist.

Answer (score 1):

your coding will be something like this:

```
$filters=array($param1,$param2,....);

$result=$this->ModelName->find('all',array('condtions'=>array('ModelName.fieldname'=>$filters)));
```

I hope this may work.